# How do I add two functions using javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, text, function-call, adventure

I'm creating a choose your own adventure game that uses a health bar and changing texts.
My health bar is able to change with my current code but the text does not. Is there something I am missing? What can I do?
The two buttons are identified with "btn q1" and it reads "Question1", and "btn q2" and it reads "Question2". I would like to change "Question1" to "Question1A", etc.
Here is my html for the buttons:

```
<div class="click">
    <span class="btn q1" id="btn q1" onclick="remove(); change();">
        Question1
    </span>
    <span class="btn q2" id="btn q2" onclick="remove(); change();">
        Question2
    </span>
</div>;
```

And my javascript:

```
var _Health = 100;

function remove() {
    let addHealth = document.getElementById("health");
    _Health += 20;

    if (addHealth) {
        addHealth.style.width = _Health + "%";
        addHealth.innerHTML = _Health + "ep";
    }
}

function remove() {
    let damage = document.getElementById("health");
    _Health -= 10;

    if (damage) {
        damage.style.width = _Health + "%";
        damage.innerHTML = _Health + "ep";
    }
}

function change() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("btn q1");
    if ((elem.value = "Question1")) elem.value = "Question1A";
    else elem.value = "Question1B";
}
function change() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("btn q2");
    if (elem.value == "Question2") elem.value = "Question2A";
    else elem.value = "Question2B";
}
```

Comment: You cannot have 2 functions with same name. You should add as argument something to know the context, and change the function to work with that. Ex: `function change(btnNr){var elem = document.getElementById("btn q"+btnNr);/* ...*/ };` and `<span class="btn q1" id="btn q1" onclick= "remove(1); change(1);">`

Answer (score 0):

You can’t create functions with same name. You should create remove1() and remove2() for example, and call them into the button. But it is not the right way: you need to generalise the functions. Consider the example of Manuel in the comment: it is enough to pass the parameter with the name of the button, and execute all the stuffs with the name passed.

```
<span class="btn_q1" id="btn_q1" onclick= "remove(10); change(“btn_q1”, “Question1A”);">Question1</span>
            <span class="btn_q2" id="btn_q2" onclick= "remove(20); change(“btn_q2”,”Question1B”);">Question2</span>
        </div>
```

And In the js:

```
    function change(btn,value)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(btn);   
elem.value = value;
    }

    function remove(n) {
    let addHealth = document.getElementById('health')
    _Health += n;

    if (addHealth) {
        addHealth.style.width = _Health + '%'; 
        addHealth.innerHTML = _Health + 'ep';
    }
}
```

Last thing: don’t use namespaces in the ids. Use underscore instead of space (same in classes)